# Understanding JS setTimeout, canvas and "Show paint rectangles" in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, canvas, settimeout

I have a question in regards to setTimeout, and "show paint rectangles" in developer console. In my application calls are issued through setTimeout at intervals of 48ms that draw on canvas quite heavily, and generally they are pretty close to that mark. However, when I enable "show paint rectangles" the setTimeout calls get delayed quite significantly, sometimes upto 100ms late. I am hypothesizing that due to additional drawing performed for "Show paint rectangles" the setTimeout calls are delayed due to the single threaded nature of JS. I was hoping to either confirm, or deny this hypothesis.

The delays cause serious problems for the application, because there is logic in there that relies on stability of timeouts - once they become very unstable drawing buffers get flushed, and user is faced with very inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Well...yes: More work == longer processing time. It's also possible your `setTimeout` calls are occasionally delayed and therefore are stacking. You might use `requestAnimationFrame` instead because it handles stacking better.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the result of a race condition. Timeouts are asynchronous and there are no guarantees they will fire at exactly the times you specify (think about it, if your processor becomes really busy or you fire off 1000 timeouts something has to yield).

You can use promises in Javascript as a solution to this sort of problem:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

This allows you to sync your tasks by waiting until a task is complete before another action fires. This is more robust than trying to rely on times.